# Is coupling functionality desired when the usage of a function can be predicted with near-perfect confidence?

Tags: dependency-injection, coupling

I have a function whose job is to look through a string that is a post's content and find certain pieces:

```
public static function findInsidePostContent( $post = Null )
{

    //post_content comes from a WP_Post object.
    $post_blocks = \parse_blocks( $post->post_content );
    //Look inside, do some things.

}
```

**The function has an absolute truth that we can always rely on:** it only and solely works with a `WP_Post` object.

But, naturally, since the parameter is `Null`, there is a clear contradiction here, so, let's try to solve it by adding a specific line right at the start of the function:

```
$post = Utils::getPostObject( $post ); if( \is_wp_error( $post ) ) return $post;
```

Great, that function is always supposed to return a `WP_Post` object, unless something wrong happened.

But what we just did was heavily couple two seemingly unconnected pieces of code and, usually, that's bad. We also hid a dependency. But what if we can predict that in all the cases, you will always work with a `WP_Post` object? You'll always have to work resolve that `WP_Post` object somewhere before:

```
$post = Utils::getPostObject( 21 );
Utils::findInsidePostContent( '', [], $post );
```

This "call path" will never, ever change.

Wouldn't the coupling be justified?

Comment: If `findInsidePostContent` must always receive a `WP_Post` object, why does the `$post` parameter have a `Null` default value?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Exactly the point of the question - to ease the process of using  `findInsidePostContent` by auto-resolving that `WP_Post` object inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets first see if calling the function `getPostObject` is justified at all, independent of the apparent coupling it produces.

The answer here depends entirely on what promises `findInsidePostContent` makes towards its callers. If `findInsidePostContent` has a precondition that it must be called with an `WP_Post` object, then inside the function there should at most be a check that the `$post` parameter really is a `WP_Post` object, but certainly no attempts to turn it into one.
On the other hand, if `findInsidePostContent` is supposed to be able to accept any argument that can be resolved into a `WP_Post` object, then the call to `getPostObject` is very legitimate.

To answer the question on coupling, I will assume that the call is legitimate.

While `getPostObject` should be blissfully unaware of the existence of `findInsidePostContent`, the latter function needs the services of `getPostObject` to do its job, because the post's content can only be accessed after it has been resolved/converted into a `WP_Post` object, which is exactly the job of `getPostObject`.

This means that the coupling is just as necessary as the coupling with `\parse_blocks` and the other functions that `findIndidePostContent` calls.